# Injectivity of the ring of formal power series over itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

It is well-known that the ring of formal power series
$F[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$, where $F$ is a field of characteristic zero, is an injective abelian group. Is it true however that $F[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ is an injective module over itself? It doesn't seem to be that clear.

While the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(-, F[[t_1, ..., t_n]])$ is clearly exact, it is not so clear if $\mathrm{Hom}_{F[[t_1, ..., t_n]]}(-, F[[t_1, ..., t_n]])$ is exact.

Comment: I'm not sure whether rings of formal power series are self-injective, but the fact that they are injective over $\mathbb{Z}$ is basically unrelated (any algebra over a field of characteristic $0$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-injective, it has nothing to do with formal series).

Comment: Yes, I agree with your statement. That is correct. I just wanted to emphasise that I am interested in the injectivity over itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An injective module over an integral domain is divisible. The power series ring is not a divisible module over itself (multiplication by $t_1$ is not surjective). This holds for $D[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$, where $D$ is any integral domain of any characteristic.

More generally still, a self-injective integral domain must be a field.

Comment: Ok, that is a good argument. The ring of formal power series in multiple indeterminates over a field (of characteristic zero at least) is an integral domain, isn't it ?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius the ring of formal power series over a field is always an integral domain